# Errors when instaling chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to install Chrome on RHEL 7 (64bit) machine but it's showing some errors.

Finished Dependency Resolution

> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.108-1.x86_64
>   (google-chrome)
>              Requires: libnss3.so(NSS_3.22)(64bit) Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-63.0.3239.108-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
>              Requires: libssl3.so(NSS_3.28)(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried the solution suggested in the error message?

Comment: ya i tried but same error massage coming..